# Cauchy's integral theorem and Green's Theorem clarification

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, greens-theorem, cauchy-riemann-equations

I was reading this page on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem

In the very end, it says that "we therefore find that both integrands (and hence their integrals) are zero". Why? Shouldn't it be a constant?

Comment: Definite integrals of a $f(x)=0$ are $0$. Maybe you are thinking of antiderivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author states that it is due to the Cauchy-Riemann equations that the integrands are zero.

And if the integrands are zero, then so are their corresponding integrals.

Comment: Yes, but if the integrands are zero, should't the integral be a constant?

Comment: No.  The definite integral of $0$ is $0$.  You're thinking about an antiderivative.

Comment: oohh thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My plleasure.